# unicode problem with apache common configuration

Tags: apache-commons-config

I am using Apache Commons Configuration for resource bundle generation. As I read from different locale bundle and writing on to target bundle the value is encoding into unicodes values which i don't want. Is there any way to write what ever we get from source bundle to target bundle

Ex:

```
Source bundle kkey and value
label.item.actionqty=MnoÅ¾stvÃ­ akce

Target bundle key and value
label.item.actionqty = Mno\u00C5\u00BEstv\u00C3\u00AD akce
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you should open a RFE in JIRA, we'll look into this.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CONFIGURATION

**EDIT**: Your suggestion has been filed in JIRA : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CONFIGURATION-457

Comment: For the time being I have done it by extending PropertiesWriter class. Thank you

Comment: I am using configuration2, but official quick_start, 
    Configuration config = configs.properties(new File("config.properties"));  throws : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospector

Comment: @Tiina adding commons-beanutils to your classpath should fix this issue